# Behavior of background in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, background

I made an webpage "show1.html" with the following code:

```
<html>
<style>
html,body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
img{
  display:block;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
</style>

<head>
    <title>Show on time</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var DJimages = [  // add path to directory if necessary
 "1.jpeg",
 "2.jpeg"  // NOTE: no comma after last entry
 ];
 function TODimage() {
 var now = new Date();
 hr = now.getHours();                               // alert(hr);  // for testing
 var DJ = 0;                                               // midnight to  5:59 am
 if ((hr >= 20) && (hr < 24)) { DJ = 1; } // 6pm to midnight
 document.getElementById('DJimage').src = DJimages[DJ];
 document.getElementById('DJimage').alt = DJimages[DJ];
 }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="TODimage()">
    <img id="DJimage" src="" alt="DJimage">
    
</body>

</html>
```

And i have a iframe page with the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head> 
      <script>
function loadFrame (elm){
    var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
    frame1.src = elm.dataset.src;
}

      </script> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <button id="b1" data-src="show1.html" onclick="loadFrame(this)">Show1</button> 
      <button id="b2" data-src="show2.html" onclick="loadFrame(this)">Show2</button> 
      <button id="b2" data-src="show3.html" onclick="loadFrame(this)">Show3</button> 
      <button id="b2" data-src="show4.html" onclick="loadFrame(this)">Show4</button> 
     </br> <iframe id="frame1" width="100%" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; overflow:hidden; border: none"></iframe>  
   </body>
</html>
```

But when i open Show1 is is not full screen i still have white on the left (and because of that i can scroll left to right)

What did i do wrong?

I first added the style code to the show1.html
That page is perfect, but once opened in iframe it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the "show1.html" page inside the iframe, it doesn't take up the full width of the iframe, and you see white space on the left side.
please add style default margin and padding for the body element:

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

If the issue still persists, it might be due to some conflicts between the parent page's styles and the iframe's styles. so you can use this code:

```
<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></iframe>
```

By resetting the margin and padding for both the iframe content and the iframe itself.